# black border on right of background image and profile image off center

Tags: html, ios, css

New to front end development. I have been trying to fix this bug through trial and error to no avail. when I inspect my page everything looks fine. when I test out my page on my Mobil phone I see this black bar to the right of my background image and my profile pic becomes off center. "cover-image;" is grayed out for "background-size" -

**here is my html code:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="cover-image">
<div class="quote">
"Prepare Today For The Wants of Tomorow." <br>- <span style="font-size:      .65em;">Aesop</span>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid">
 <div id="about" class="row">
 <div id="profile-pic" class="col-md-5 col-md-push-1 col-xs-8 rounded-img text-center">
 <div id="text-content">Circuit de Catalunya Montmelo<br>Barcelona, Spain</div>
  </div>
  <div id="about-content" class="col-md-7 col-md-push-2 col-xs-12">
```

My CSS code:

```
    .cover-image {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    background: #D3D3D3 url("../images/surfers.jpeg");
    background-position:center;;
    background-size: cover-image;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 105%;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0.9;
    }
```

[image: portfolio website]

Answer (score 0):

Might be wrong here, but I think the property you're looking for is "cover", not "cover-image".

Comment: background-size cover is greyed out as well

Comment: @User-09 I know lol that's not a valid CSS property :) you want to use background-size: cover; instead.

Comment: "background-size: contain" is greyed out as well. I have adjusted the width 105%. The black bar is gone in chrome, but I can still see it when I test my page on my mobil phone

Comment: Did you try using just cover?

Comment: yeah, greyed out. I'm going to try and experiment with media query

Comment: or maybe its my column grids

Answer (score 0):

Theres a syntax error above `background-size: cover;`

It appears to have an extra semi-colon, which may give it the greyed out effect. Remove that and then just do the above line instead of `background-size: cover-image;` As that is not valid at all.

You could also try:

```
background-image: contain;
```

Comment: i might have to post all my html and css code. I know its something obvious that I am missing lol!

Comment: As a question, Have you even tried any of the things people have suggested?